# How to split incoming Json objects array in Spring XD?

Tags: arrays, json, spring-xd, splitter

Let's say my incoming data is a json object or an array of json objects.
I want to split the incoming json data iff it's an array so that I can insert them into a MongoDB collection (For simplicity, let's just log to console for now).

1. Define Stream

   xd:>stream create splittest --definition "http | json-to-tuple | splitter | log" --deploy
2. Post a single object

   xd:>http post --data "{\"dog\": \"chihuahua\"}"

   21T09:05:59-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO pool-44-thread-4 sink.splittest - {"dog":"chihuahua"}

   This is expected output as the input was a single object - nothing to split.
3. Post an array of Objects

   xd:>http post --data "[{\"dog\": \"poodle\"}, {\"dog\": \"chihuahua\"}, {\"dog\":\"poodle\"}]"

   21T09:43:05-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO pool-44-thread-11 sink.splittest - {}

   In this case, I expected to see three individual dog objects printed in each line but it printed a single empty object.

What am I doing wrong?  Can somebody suggest what could/should have been done?

Comment: It seems, since your POST handler deals with one dog fine, but not an array of dogs, that the error is in the code that handles the POST request, not the commands that send said request. If you post this code, I will try to assist you.

Comment: The second post returned 200 OK and the server didn't throw any error.  It printed exactly shown as above.   And there's no code for doing this.  I've done this using pure spring integration but I didn't want to bother writing customer transformer and splitter for Spring XD.   I am trying to use the out-of-box features of XD as much as I can.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familar enough with Spring XD to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do that.   I didn't need to bother using json-to-tuple processor.

```
xd:>stream create splittest2 --definition "http | splitter --expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.[*]') | log" --deploy

xd:>http post --data "[{\"dog\": \"poodle\"}, {\"dog\": \"chihuahua\"}, {\"dog\":\"poodle\"}]"

2015-10-21T10:52:31-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO pool-83-thread-4 sink.splittest2 - {dog=poodle}
2015-10-21T10:52:31-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO pool-83-thread-4 sink.splittest2 - {dog=chihuahua}
2015-10-21T10:52:31-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO pool-83-thread-4 sink.splittest2 - {dog=poodle}
```

So it works on the multiple objects, however, it doesn't handle single object as I expected.

```
xd:>http post --data "{\"dog\":\"chihuahua\"}"
2015-10-21T10:56:11-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO pool-83-thread-10 sink.splittest2 - chihuahua
```

Comment: Maybe this one `$..*`?

Comment: Close enough.   It splits the array (which is what I want) AND splits each dog.

Comment: sink.splittest2 - {dog=poodle}
    sink.splittest2 - {dog=chihuahua}
    sink.splittest2 - {dog=poodle}
    sink.splittest2 - poodle
    sink.splittest2 - chihuahua
    sink.splittest2 - poodle